# SQL count grouping every 2 hours

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i counting and grouping every 2 hours ?

i have a table like this:

```
Id  TheTime
--  -------
1   07/07/2012 08:49:02
2   07/07/2012 09:36:39
3   07/07/2012 10:36:39
4   07/07/2012 12:36:39
5   07/07/2012 13:36:39
```

how can i convert into :

```
TheTime_08_10  TheTime_10_12  TheTime_12_14 etc.. until TheTime_22_00
-------------  -------------  ------------              -------------
       2              1            2
```

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a database which supports Hour() function, you can use:

```
SELECT Floor(Hour(TheTime)/2)*2, COUNT(*) FROM TimeTable GROUP BY Floor(Hour(TheTime)/2)
```

You will get something like this:

```
Floor(...) | Count(*)
---------------------
8          | 1
10         | 3
12         | 5
16         | 1
```

The first column is the starting hour - `8` means time from 8:00 to 9:59, etc.

Comment: i use SQL 2008 R2, apparently Hour is not function of SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Try to replace Hour(TheTime) with DATEPART(hh, TheTime).

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of examples of this type of problem on StackOverflow. Use simple case statements. Make sure you understand the business rules around the boundaries.

```
Select 
  Sum(Case When Datepart(hh, TheTime) Between 8 and 9 Then 1 Else 0 End) TheTime_8_10,
  ....
```